# Weka discretising attribute where one value is most common by far

Tags: weka, data-mining

I have a dataset in which there's a numerical attribute for the 'number of days since last contact' but the value -1 is being used to indicate that there hasn't been a last contact. It is by far the largest value for this attribute.

My idea is to discretise this attribute but how can I ensure there is a 'no contact'/-1 bin?

Also, is this the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: "My idea is to discretise this attribute but how can I ensure there is a 'no contact'/-1 bin?"  It is not clear what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this question and can't find an answer, here's how I did it based on Anony-Mousse's method. The filter documentation for MathExpression gives a good example of splitting into arbitrary bins.

1. Split using the MathExpression filter e.g. ifelse(A>0, 2, 1)  to split into two bins: above and below 0. I used ifelse(A>0, ifelse(A>400, 21, ceil(A/20)+1), 1) to bin my -1 and >400 values, and for in between values to be in bins of width 20.
2. Convert using numericToNominal

Answer (score 1):

The proper approach supposedly is to

1. Split the data into -1 and everything else
2. Apply binning to the values in the 'everything else' set only
3. Concatenate the data sets again (it may be good to shuffle, too)

Comment: Thanks for your help, though how do I do step 1? I can't see a filter that would achieve this. Do you have to do it manually?

Comment: I don't know about the GUI, and I don't use Weka much. This is a programming website, and it should be easy to do this with Java.